# "Preselect" the object type for "WhatId" on a Global Action to create a new event?

Tags: global-actions, whatid

I have a Global Action to create a new Event record, and I would like to be able to specify (or preselect) that the Related To lookup field (WhatId) should be Account.  When this action is launched from the global actions icon (+), it defaults the Related To lookup to the object that is alphabetically first (Accomplishments). [image: GLobal Action] But when the same action is added to an Account page layout, the same field defaults to the Account object. [image: Global action from account page]

Is there any way I can have the Global Action "predefined" to use the Account object in the Related To (WhatId) field?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly coerce the `Related To` to be a specific SObject Type for a Global Action

What you could do is remove Related To from the Global Action layout and replace it with a custom lookup field to Account.

Then, use a before save flow to move (i.e. copy and clear the copy source) the custom field to `Event.WhatId`